# Dataset returned by module is not reactive

Tags: r, shiny

Here's an example:

```
library(shiny)

mod_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    "tab 2",
    actionButton(ns("change_dataset"), "change dataset")
  )

}

mod_server <- function(input, output, session){

  data <- reactive({ mtcars })

  observeEvent(input$change_dataset, {
    data <- reactive({ iris })
    # Comment the line above and uncomment the 
    # one below to check that this button works:
    # print("button works")
  })

  return(
    list(
      data_1 = data
    )
  )

}

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "",
  id = "a_navbar",
  tabPanel(
    "tab 1",
    dataTableOutput("data_test")
  ),
  mod_ui("tab_2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  mod_return <- callModule(mod_server, "tab_2")

  output$data_test <- renderDataTable({
    mod_return$data_1()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Basically, this app displays the `mtcars` dataset in tab 1, and it should display the `iris` dataset if the user clicks on the button "change dataset" in tab 2. But clicking on this button does not update the table. Why is this the case? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should avoid nesting reactives in observers.

You can use `eventReactive` instead. Please check the following:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mod_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel("tab 2",
           actionButton(ns("change_dataset"), "change dataset"))

}

mod_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- eventReactive(input$change_dataset, {
    if (input$change_dataset %% 2) {
      iris
    } else {
      mtcars
    }
  }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

  return(list(data_1 = data))

}

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "",
  id = "a_navbar",
  tabPanel("tab 1",
           DT::dataTableOutput("data_test")),
  mod_ui("tab_2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mod_return <- callModule(mod_server, "tab_2")

  output$data_test <- DT::renderDataTable({
    mod_return$data_1()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Another approach would be to set a `reactiveVal` in the `observeEvent`.

Comment: With this, the user needs to click once on the button to display the `iris` dataset whereas I would like `mtcars` to be displayed by default (without action needed)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to validate your answer. Yes it works (but I have some trouble applying this to my real app, I'm trying to figure this out)